# api routes doesn't work in laravel when upload it on subdomain?

Tags: php, laravel

i want to upload my laravel app on my subdomain and use it as restapi but when tried to call subdomain.com/api/test i got **404 Not Found** 
but subdomain.com is worked fine so i don't know where the problem 
here my index.php file

```
/**
 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
 *
 * @package  Laravel
 * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylor@laravel.com>
 */

define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register The Auto Loader
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader for
| our application. We just need to utilize it! We'll simply require it
| into the script here so that we don't have to worry about manual
| loading any of our classes later on. It feels great to relax.
|
*/

require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Turn On The Lights
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| We need to illuminate PHP development, so let us turn on the lights.
| This bootstraps the framework and gets it ready for use, then it
| will load up this application so that we can run it and send
| the responses back to the browser and delight our users.
|
*/

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Run The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Once we have the application, we can handle the incoming request
| through the kernel, and send the associated response back to
| the client's browser allowing them to enjoy the creative
| and wonderful application we have prepared for them.
|
*/

$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

and here my api.php

```
Route::get('/test', function () {
    return  json_encode(Twitter::getMentionsTimeline(['screen_name' => 'abanoubwagih94', 'count' => 200, 'include_rts' => '1']));
});
```

there is .htaccess i don't know how to set it to access my subdomain

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

any help please...

Comment: Well, `subdomain.com/api/` doesn't match the route that you posted... It would be `subdomain.com/api/test`

Comment: doesn't work too

Comment: You are talking about two different host names, regardless they are sub or not. You have to checkout the rewrite URL settings of your second host's server. i.e if you use Apache checkout the mod rewrite or the .htaccess configurations

Comment: @SaidbakR  how to set it in .htaccess ?

Comment: Checkout it in the `public` directory of your project but show all files there.